# Deploy to Android Device: Unknown module(s) in QT

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-creator

Trying to run my project test in Android Device I receive this message `QML module not found (QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard)`. I Checked my apt list and I have those libaries installed.

```
qml-module-qtquick-virtualkeyboard/bionic 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64
qtvirtualkeyboard-plugin/bionic 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64
qtvirtualkeyboard5-examples/bionic 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1 amd64
```

This error does not occur when I deploy to Dekstop.

Comment: The Qt installed by apt-get does not serve to compile a project for android.

Comment: So, how I can properly deploy to my own android device?

Comment: did you try to install a proper version through the Qt maintenance tool?